# ActionBarSherlock remove blue divider line

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to remove the lightblue divider line below the ActionBar when I use ActionBarSherlock.

I found something like this and added it to my styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

But it doesn't work, the line is still there. Is there any possibility to achieve what I want? Or maybe is it possible to change its color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Style generator to see what can be customised and how to do it.

http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/